# PHP-FPM with apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, web-server, php-fpm

Is it possible to run PHP-FPM with Apache or is that a nginx only option?

Looking for ways to use apache and keep .htaccess but gain better php performance like able to take more reqs per sec.

EDIT: I also run nginx as a front-end reverse proxy for static content.

Answer (score 2):

PHP-FPM is PHP FastCGI process manager. Fastcgi is protocol for communication between application server and webserver. FastCGI is supported for all major web servers - apache2, lighttpd, nginx, cherokee, IIS.

For Apache 2.4, you can use [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html). Apache 2.4 is recommended because of performance improvements and new super-fast mpm_event engine. For older Apache versions you have to rely on third party [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://mproxyfcgi.sourceforge.net/), because bundled mod_fcgid does not work with externally spawned processes like phpf-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. According to me Nginx is more flexible, light loaded server than Apache. I am personally using Nginx to run php-fpm.

Comment: I run shared hosting so I can't drop Apache. I've setup a social network on varnish/nginx+php-fpm and they run good.